# GIMP 2.8 doesn't allow to save usual image file formats (jpg, png) via Save dialog

Tags: gimp, png, jpeg

I used to save images as usual image file formats (jpg, png) by pressing Ctrl+S or Ctrl+Shift+S (Save or Save As dialog). Now in version 2.8 GIMP doesn't allow it anymore: you can Save only as .xcf but to save as .jpg or .png you must Export.

Is there a way to get this old file saving functionality back?

Comment: Here is my approach to this new "feature": http://askubuntu.com/questions/284493/avoid-save-for-web-in-gimp

Comment: What do u do if Export and Flatten are ghosted?

Comment: It's basically bad product design, and it commits a product design sin.  What they were thinking was: "People aren't using Export like we want them to. Let's break the Save feature to prevent them using it the want they want, forcing them to use Export instead".  What they should have done: "People aren't using Export like we want them to.  Let's find out what they are doing instead and re-consider having this separate Export feature".

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why the fix for this wasn't just a "Save Project" button or something for users that really did want to make sure they saved a .xcf file; this change is very annoying when all you want to do is convert an image file from one format to another or do a quick copy/paste or edit to an image file.

Comment: GIMP `2.10.32`  have overwrite option now, to write on the same file you opened .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I remember reading on [heise (german)](http://www.heise.de/open/meldung/Plug-in-fuer-Gimp-2-8-bringt-Speichern-von-PNG-und-JPG-zurueck-1672440.html) that [someone wrote a plugin to revert back to the old functionality](https://github.com/akkana/gimp-plugins/blob/master/save-export-clean.py).

Runnning the following commands in a terminal will download the latest version of the plugin to Gimp 2.8's config directory and make it executable:

```
gimp_dir=".gimp-2.8"
wget https://github.com/akkana/gimp-plugins/raw/master/save-export-clean.py -O ~/${gimp_dir}/plug-ins/save-export-clean.py
chmod a+x ~/${gimp_dir}/plug-ins/save-export-clean.py
```

But I have to say that it's not a big deal learning the new shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. Also having a clean distinction between destructive export and save is actually a good thing.

Comment: Great! Now if only this plugin could 'steal' Ctrl+S and Ctrl+Shift+S shortcuts...

Comment: Of course you can bind it to Ctrl+S. Simply go to **Edit | Keyboard Shortcuts**, search for **Save/Export clean** and assign it to Ctrl+S.

Comment: Vote up this answer for the ctrl+E command!

Comment: An important comment from the top of the script: `Warning: this does not show a lot of extra dialogs, etc. or warn you if you're about to overwrite something! Use with caution.`

Comment: You can use Ctrl+E as export instead of Ctrl+S (or even rebind "export as" to Ctrl+S), but it's not perfect, GIMP doesn't consider an "export" a "save", so when you close the image you'll get a "do you want to save" prompt even though you already technically "saved".

Answer (score 13):

Starting from GIMP 2.8 we need to use the "File → Export" or "File → Export to..." menu entries, or alternatively the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> keyboard shortcuts respectively, which will result in the Export dialog to allow you to save the work in your favorite image format.

The former <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is now used to work with the project only. To save the project or "Save as" the project.

Good luck!

[image]

### For the comment of @Eric Leschinski I am dropping this edit:

That's about how you use your software. Many people uses mouse and it's ok if they love to do so. Personally I made my process as OpenFile/Tweak/Export/CloseFile[CloseGIMP] in a faster way by doing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>/Tweak/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>[<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>] and it takes 3~5 seconds (depending on your machine's speed. For the "Save as" Process it takes just one more step but it did the same before. So I suggest you to start by tweaking your key binding in order to make it faster. Good luck!

Comment: @EricLeschinski I added an edit for you.

Comment: Changing the process of: Openfile/tweak/ctrl-s/exit operation into "openfile/tweak/ctrl-e/ctrl-w/ctrl-q" seems like someone trying to completely ruin the one thing that image editors are supposed to be good at: editing images.  Why not add 5 more keyboard combinations to the mix so it takes 20 minutes to edit an image?  Whoever responsible for this needs to be punched.

Comment: Changing the process of whatever the Software did before seems like someone is inviting us to evolve with the upgrades. It's on ourselves to choose whether to accept the challenge or not. Good luck on whatever you choose, my friend!

Comment: Any explanation to why this clear regression in behavior was accepted? Clearly not an improvement in any way!

Comment: That's a good question for GIMP Forums (http://gimpforums.com/). In my opinion, saving and exporting are two different things, and people used to work with multimedia (audio and video) understand the difference with ease. Let's say saving is a non-destructive process to save the current state of the work and exporting is a destructive process when you don't save with a different name. So, I think it's useful to have separate processes for these things. But as I mention, it's my opinion, not a rule and I am not starting a debate. Good luck!

Comment: While the idea of *inventing* such a workflow is certainly to be welcomed, the idea to *force it upon the users* is definitely not. It should be made optional, so those who want it can enable it and those who don't can stick with the "easier" way – which after all is how the majority is used to work. </rant> But that's nothing we can solve here at AU, that must be addressed at the Gimp team. Luckily, there are at least some work-arounds, as described in the other answers. [The one by Smile4ever](/a/625966/68291) works great for me.

Comment: PS: Added a note on the request to the Gimp tracker [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=776108#c2). Not sure whether it will be honored, though, as Gimp team behaves Gnomish ("that's not the way you should use it – use it as we define") :(

Answer (score 1):

Press ctrl+E and you will be able to save it in other formats like jpg png or go to file and click on Export.... and you will be able to save it.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from GIMP 2.8, the behaviour changed:

- XCF is now the default format for saving images. This is because of the non-destructive nature of this file format: it retains the layers in the image.
- PNG/JPEG are import and export formats. Use File -> Open to import these and File -> Export (or Overwrite) to save PNG/JPEG images.

This change was done to prevent people from accidentally losing their layers. However, this change has received immense criticism from many users.

To revert to the old behaviour as was the case in GIMP 2.6, follow these steps:

- Download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akkana/gimp-plugins/master/saver.py
- Save to `~/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/` (so the location becomes something like `/home/myuser/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/saver.py`)
- Make saver.py executable: `chmod +x saver.py`
- Restart GIMP
- Go to Edit -> Shortcuts and search for "Saver"
- Assign the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to "Saver". Confirm you want to reassign the shortcut.
- Assign the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to "Saver as". Confirm you want to reassign the shortcut.

Now you can simply use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (save) and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (save as) to save your files. Also, on exit GIMP won't ask to save your files to XCF anymore (if they have already been saved with saver).

Now train yourself: in the File menu, use "Saver" and "Saver as". This two commands replace these 4 items: Save / Save As / Export / Export as. So click "Saver" or "Saver as" from now on :)