# GIMP saves as xcf extension

Tags: gimp

I used to use Irfanview to edit my files but it stopped working a couple of days ago so I switched to GIMP but I can't seem to find a way to save a file other than xcf.

Comment: also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/284493/avoid-save-for-web-in-gimp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select file => save as => select type by file extension => jpg or any other extension you want

[image: save as]

Comment: Or include the extension in the filename. GIMP will automatically choose the right format (e.g.: type in DCIM001.jpg)

Comment: Aha, did not know that

Comment: This does the trick!

Comment: Wont work in Gimp 2.8. - it will complain about extensions other than XCF or compressed XCF.

Answer (score 1):

In fact in GIMP you save your file as xcf and you **export** it to the file type you want (including all major file types).

You can use <kbd>SHIFT + CTRL + E</kbd> for this purpose or simply "File / Export." Saving the file in xcf allows you to do a lot more editing if you reopen the file later.

Comment: Can it be that this doesn't work in GIMP version 2.6?

Comment: At present Gimp is at 2.8. - older versions do not have the issue on save as as it was asked by the OP.

Comment: Appearantly I still use version 2.6 and the shortcut doesn't work in my version. That's why I made the remark